# How to setup bindings for NSPopUpButton

Tags: cocoa, selection, cocoa-bindings, nspopupbutton

I want to bind selection of NSPopUpButton to one of the predefined values. To make it simpler, imagine a blog app: I'd have `BlogPost` and `Category` entities (Core Data, although it doesn't matter) and each `BlogPost` object has a link to one of the `Category` objects (through `category` property).

I want to have the user change the category through NSPopUpButton, so in my XIB, I have NSArrayController that holds all possible categories and I bind button's *Content Values* to:

- Bind to: *categoriesArrayController*
- Controller key: *arrangedObjects*
- Model key: *title*

This nicely populates pop up with titles of all categories. I can also bind *Selected Object* to:

- Bind to: *blogObjectController* (or directly to `Blog` object)
- Controller key: *selection*
- Model key: *category*

This works and correct category is selected in pop up, however changing selection doesn't change the category under which the blog post is filed, but instead changes the title of post category to the selected value.

Given the above bindings this actually makes sense, so my next step was to change the binding of pop up's content values to only *arrangedObjects* (no model key), similarly selected object. This works and changing selection does indeed change `category` of the blog post to another one. **BUT** it doesn't show category title in pop up menu, but instead shows the `description` of the category (which in Core data ends with something like `<Category 0x1002b6990> (entity: Category; id: .......)`.

Which also makes sense, so I introduced custom `NSValueTransformer` (non-reversible). This fixes item descriptions in pop up menu, but then selection doesn't work. I also tried using the transformer on selected object binding, but that just disables my pop up entirely (perhaps reverse transform would be required, but this would substantially complicate transformer).

Am I missing something obvious - is this possible to achive entirely with bindings, without introducing additional code on controller layer?

Any though is welcome!

PS: hope above text makes sense :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would try it as follows:

Of NSPopupButton:

- Bind **Content** to : *categoriesArrayController* ControllerKey: `arrangedObjects`
- Bind **Content Values** to : *categoriesArrayController* ControllerKey: `arrangedObjects` Model Key Path: *title*
- Bind **Selected Object** to : *blogObjectController* ControllerKey: `(empty)` Model Key Path: *content.category*

Comment: That's it, I remember now, thanks :) I was confused as *Content values* was disabled, only *Content* was allowed.